# Protection level of a struct field within a class

Tags: c#, struct, visibility

I get a *"'A.Test.That.Fails' is inaccessible due to its protection level"* error on the following code snippet and I fail to understand the reason.

```
namespace A
{
    class Test
    {
        public void Demo()
        {
            That[] it = new That[42];
            it[0].fails = 21;
        }

        public struct That
        {
            int fails;
        }
    }
}
```

Coming from C++ programming and having read that protection rules are almost the same, since there is a single class I would expect it to work even if both the `That` struct and the `Demo` method were `private`.

As the side note, a link to some page summing up scope and protection rules toward the C++ programmer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `A.Test.That.fails`... clever. +1

Comment: See Cody's answer; there is a big difference between structs and classes in C#; they are barely related, in fact. Most times that people use a struct in C#, it is incorrect. Make sure you are using it for the right reason. "Because it is a simple object" is not such a reason.

Comment: @BoltClock: ;)

@Marc: will "because I just want a quick array of scalar pairs" do as an excuse?

Comment: Yes, I'd say so. Not necessarily because it's simple or quick, but because you want value type semantics for those scalar pairs. They should work just like a regular `int`, not like an object. It makes logical sense that they be immutable. I'd choose a struct for that, too.

Comment: On a tangential note: In the case that you don't *want* your internals public but need them to be public anyhow, `InternalsVisibleTo` allows you to make an internal class visible to a specific external assembly.  This is mostly useful for unit-testing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The other answers given already have your answer, so I won't beat a dead horse here. You need to declare the field `public` in order to be able to access it from external code.

In C++, structs and classes are equivalent, with the only difference being the default access level of their respective members.

However, that's not the case in C#. Generally, you should only use a struct for small, short-lived objects that are immutable (won't change). A structure has *value type* semantics, where as a class has *reference type* semantics. It's very important that you understand the difference between value types and reference types if you're learning to program in C#. Jon Skeet has published [an article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/references.html) that attempts to provide that explanation. But you'll definitely want to pick up a good introductory book to C# that treats these issues in more detail.

More often than not, you'll want to use a class in C#, rather than a structure. And when you use that class, note that Microsoft's design guidelines for C# tend to recommend *against* exposing public fields. Instead, they recommend that you use a public property, backed by a private field. A more thorough exposition of the rationale behind that guideline is given [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx). For example:

```
class TimePeriod
{
    private double seconds;

    public double Seconds
    {
        get { return seconds; }
        set { seconds = value; }
    }
}
```

Or you can use the simpler "automatic properties" syntax, which has the compiler automatically generate that private backing field:

```
class TimePeriod
{
    public double Seconds { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yep, for the sake of the example I did put public, but in real life things go as private as possible indeed, and this ability to define set/get clearly helps. Thank you for the overview and link.

Comment: @Julien: Of course. I assumed the example was contrived for demonstration purposes only. Obviously in the real world there are indeed legitimate cases where you want to use a struct. Not only for value type semantics, but also for interop purposes. But in general, objects are best modeled using a class in C#.

Comment: +1 Win32 interop has forced me into egregious use of structs in my WPF app... and I'm detesting it.

Comment: @Bolt: But of course, I assume that you've placed all those structs in a separate namespace and/or assembly, and declared them either private or internal. I always write a nice, clean managed wrapper class over the interop code, which is the only thing I expose publically.

Answer (score 4):

The default access modifier in C# for struct fields (and class fields) is `private`. So `int fails;` is private to your struct, unless you declare it public.

Comment: Default for class fields is `internal` not `private`

Comment: @Monty: No, internal is the default for classes themselves. Their members are private by default.

Answer (score 2):

please see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763612/default-visibility-for-c-classes-and-members-fields-methods-etc)

That member is being declared private by default - you need to put the `public` modifier before it.

Answer (score 2):

Because `fails` is not `public`.. by default fields  in `struct` and even `class` are `private`

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

> The **access level** for **class** members and **struct** members, including nested classes and structs, is **private** by **default**.

Comment: Ok I got it, not like C/C++ where struct fields are public by default. Thank you.

Comment: you're welcome.. i have added a link to MSDN doc for your reference . :)

Answer (score 1):

Private members of Test restrict to Test itself and are not available outside of Test. Demo is outside of Test.  It doesn't matter who the parent is.

Define Demo inside Test and you can access the private members.

Comment: Of course.  It is not inside the definition of Test, so it is outside.  QED.  To be inside it needs to be within the braces of the Test struct itself.