# My struct "does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments" ... but it does

Tags: c#, struct, constructor

Im trying to add cards to a list. The cards are structs. In my struct I have a constructor that takes a value and a suit. When I try to create a new card, I get the error "'Blackjack.Program.Card' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments"
As you can see though, it does. This is my code.

```
public struct Card
{
    int value;
    string suit;

    Card(int _value, string _suit)
    {
        value = _value;
        suit = _suit;
    }
};

public List<Card> deck = new List<Card>();


static void shuffleNewDeck(ref List<Card> newDeck)
{
    newDeck.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) // add spades
    {
        newDeck.Add(new Card(i, "Spade")); // error here

    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: `newDeck` does not need to be `ref`, because you are not assigning to it. I suspect that a better signature would be `static List<Card> ShuffleNewDeck()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `public` to your `Card` constructor.

Answer (score 4):

Change the constructor accessor to public

something like

```
public struct Card
{
    int value;
    string suit;

    public Card(int _value, string _suit)
    {
        value = _value;
        suit = _suit;
    }
}
```

From [Private Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcfb85a6.aspx)

> Note that if you do not use an access modifier with the constructor it
>   will still be private by default.

Answer (score 1):

Structs and classes in c# are by default are private. you have to modify your code Like:

```
public struct Card
{
    int value;
    string suit;

    public Card(int _value, string _suit)
    {
        value = _value;
        suit = _suit;
    }
};
```

**EDIT**

I have changed my answer with reference to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456463/protection-level-of-a-struct-field-within-a-class)

Comment: _In classes by default all members are public, but in structs it is opposite i.e. all members are private_ **this is incorrect, the default is `private`**

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri the default is private for classes too.

Comment: @Blorgbeard i have fixed my answer. previously i had c/c++ in mind. thanks for pointing in right direction. :) If you plz remove downvote now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor isn't public.

```
public Card(int _value, string _suit)
```