# IronPython Static Program Class Visibility

Tags: import, ironpython

I'm new to IronPython but have been using Python for many years. I inherited some C# applications and would like to access some of their classes via Python. Given the following C#:

```
namespace Updater {
    static class Program {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
            //Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault( false );
            Application.Run( new Form1() );
        }
    }
}
```

When I import in Python:

```
>>> clr.AddReferenceToFile('Updater.exe')
>>> import Updater
>>> dir(Updater)
['Form1']
```

Why isn't Program visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default visibility to classes in C# is `internal`, so IronPython won't show the `Program` class. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3763638/129592 for more info.

You can fix it by changing the class declaration to

```
public static class Program {
    // etc.
}
```