# C# get/set inaccessibility error

Tags: c#, get, set

I am getting an error as followed:
Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'AudioDevices.Tracks.track.Time' is less accessible than property 'AudioDevices.Tracks.track.length'

I have no clue what it is, or how i can fix it. Anybody that can help me?

This is all the code i have, [template = class library]:

```
namespace AudioDevices.Tracks
{
public class Track
{
    #region STRUCT           
    private int id;
    private string name;
    private string artist;
    private string albumSource;
    private Time length;
    private category style;
    public enum category{
        Ambient, Blues, Country, Disco, Electro, Hardcore, HardRock, HeavyMetal,            Hiphop, Jazz, Jumpstyle,
        Klassiek, Latin, Other, Pop, Punk, Reggae, Rock, Soul, Trance, Techno
    };
    #endregion

    #region GET/SET          
    public int Id{
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
    public string Name{
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    public string Artist{
        get { return artist; }
        set { artist = value; }
    }
    public string AlbumSource{
        get { return albumSource; }
        set { albumSource = value; }
    }
    public Time Length{
        set { length = value; }
    }

    public string DisplayTime
    {
        get { return length.ToString(); }
    }
    public category Style
    {
        get { return style; }
        set { style = value; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region TIME CONSTRUCTOR 
    struct Time
    {
        int seconds;
        int minutes;
        int hours;

        public Time(int seconds)
        {
            this.seconds = seconds;
            this.minutes = 0;
            this.hours = 0;
        }

        public Time(int seconds, int minutes)
        {
            this.seconds = seconds;
            this.minutes = minutes;
            this.hours = 0;
        }

        public Time(int seconds, int minutes, int hours)
        {
            this.seconds = seconds;
            this.minutes = minutes;
            this.hours = hours;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
           return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region TRACK CONSTRUCTOR

    public Track(){     }

    public Track(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Track(int id, string name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Track(int id, string name, string artist)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.artist = artist;
    }
    #endregion

    #region GetLength
    public string GetLength()
    {
        return length.ToString();
    }

    public int GetLengthInSeconds(int seconds, int minutes, int hours){
        int SecondsToSeconds = seconds;
        int MinutesToSeconds = minutes * 60;
        int HoursToSeconds = hours * 3600;

        int TotalSeconds = HoursToSeconds + MinutesToSeconds + SecondsToSeconds;
        return TotalSeconds;
    }
    #endregion 



}
```

}

Comment: It has been fixed! Thanks for the help everybody!

Comment: for future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763612/default-visibility-for-c-sharp-classes-and-members-fields-methods-etc

Comment: As an FYI, the *reason* this is an error is that some other class will be able to see `Length` (since it is public) but not `Time` (since it is private).  Basically, your original code says: *Anyone can set the length by passing in a Time object.  What is a Time object? That's a secret! ::Sticks out tongue::*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a *public* property here:

```
public Time Length{
    set { length = value; }
}
```

... but the type of that property is `Time`, which is a *private* type:

```
struct Time {
   ...
}
```

(It's private because it's a nested type; if it were declared as a top-level type it would be internal by default, which would still have the same problem.)

Public member signatures can't refer to private or internal types anywhere in the parameter types or return type. The member simply wouldn't be meaningful to the caller if they were in a different assembly.

So, the fix is to *either* make `Time` a public type (and I'd recommend extracting it as a top-level type at the same time) *or* to make `Time` a private property.

Comment: wow, i changed it to public struct time. and it worked. i finally know what the problem was. And why there was a problem. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you are using a construct Time.

Try to alter your code like:

```
  public Time Length{
        set { length = new Time(value); }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From *[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)*;

> The access level for class members and struct members, including
>   nested classes and structs, is **private** by default.

So, your `Time` struct is `private` by default.

On this part;

```
public Time Length
{
    set { length = value; }
}
```

You are trying to create `public` property the type of `private` struct. You can't do that. For fixing it,

- Change your `Length` property access modifier `public` to `private`.

or

- Set your `Time` struct access modifier to `public`.