# Private & Public declarations in C#

Tags: c#

Is there a way in C# to declare a group of variables and methods as private or public like in C++ (example below).  I am just trying to avoid typing a million "public"s and "private"s.

```
class Foo
 {
   private:
    int Alpha;
    string Dog;

   public:
    bool Bites;
    bool Bad;
  }
```

I keep getting an error in C# and have exhausted my internet search abilities. Thanks

Comment: Some text editors allow multiline editing as a way to make this easier. In Visual Studio, hold Alt and drag to select the same column on multiple lines. I sometimes do this when I have a lot of fields and don't feel like retyping `private` for each one.

Comment: Genius @RobertRouhani!!  I just tried it. Saves a ton of typing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You need to specify visibility for each member.

`private` is default for members, so it is safe to omit it (unless your coding guidelines tell you must specify). More details/links - [Default visibility for C# classes and members (fields, methods, etc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763612/default-visibility-for-c-sharp-classes-and-members-fields-methods-etc)