# Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: return type is less accessible than method

Tags: c#, winforms, access-modifiers

When I'm building, VS show error. This is my code:

```
public Composite buildComposite(ComboBox subs, ComboBox bas)
{
    int count = 0;
    Composite a = new Composite();
    if (subs.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        foreach (Substance d in listSubstance)
        {
            if (String.Compare(d.notation, subs.Text) == 0)
            {
                count++;
                a.subs = new Substance(d);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (bas.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        foreach (Base g in listBase)
        {
            if (String.Compare(g.notation, bas.Text) == 0)
            {
                count++;
                a.bas = new Base(g);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (count > 0)
    {
        a.equilibrium();
        a.settypesubs(arrayDefinition);
        return a;
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

This is my error:

> Error 1   Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'Project_HGHTM9.Composite' is less accessible than method 'Project_HGHTM9.Form1.buildComposite(System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox, System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox)'   c:\users\nguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Project_HGHTM9\Project_HGHTM9\Form1.cs    172 26  Project_HGHTM9

Comment: Your `Composite` class should be public. Go ahead and change that

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory.  What bout it don't you understand?

Comment: You can't return a type from a public method that isn't public itself.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Your `Composite` class is not `public`.  You can't return a non-public type from a public method.

If you don't specify an accessibility for a non-nested class then `internal` is used by default.  Add `public` to your `Composite` class definition:

```
public class Composite
{
    ...
```

Alternatively, if `buildComposite` doesn't *need* to be `public` (meaning it's only used internally by the form), then you could make the method `private` or `internal` as well:

```
private Composite buildComposite(ComboBox subs, ComboBox bas)
{
    ....
```

Answer (score 5):

you are trying to return an instance of class `Composite` from a public method, but `Composite` is not public therefore can't be returned as any calling code cannot know anything about the `Composite` class as it cannot see it.

Make your `Composite` class public.

```
public class Composite{...}
```

or make your method which is returning your `Composite` have the same visibility as your class (probably private):

```
private Composite buildComposite(ComboBox subs, ComboBox bas)
```

Which of these is appropriate will depend on whether you need to call the method (or use the class) from outside your current assembly.

By default a class is usually as 'hidden' as it can be, so private for classes.  Read more about the default visibility [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763612/default-visibility-for-c-sharp-classes-and-members-fields-methods-etc)

Answer (score 0):

Your custom type, Composite, is currently less accessible than your method buildComposite. For other classes to see this public method, they must also have public access to the Composite class/struct.

Answer (score 0):

if `Composite` was defined in unreachable/unmodifiable code like `class Composite`, you could try making `buildComposite` as internal. Like 
`internal Composite buildComposite(ComboBox subs, ComboBox bas)`. This way it is still more accessible by making the method *private*.