# inaccessible due to its protection level, trying to add objects to list

Tags: c#, wpf

Error:

```
'FileProtect.FileUrl._url' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

Getting the above error for some reason, all i'm trying to do is put a collection of objects in a List...

```
public void load()
        {
            string test = "C:\\Users\\Martyn Ball\\Desktop\\";
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@test);

            foreach (string tmp in filePaths)
            {
                //Add file url to custom object
                FileUrl fileInfo = new FileUrl();
                fileInfo.url = tmp;

                //Is it file/folder

                //Add to list
                currentFolder.Add(fileInfo);
            }
        }
```

Here is the class:

```
public class FileUrl
    {
        string url { get; set; }
        int filefolder { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class members are `private` by default, so your class is defined like this:

```
public class FileUrl
{
    private string url { get; set; }
    private int filefolder { get; set; }
}
```

Thus, those properties can't be accessed from outside the object, which you try to do here:

```
FileUrl fileInfo = new FileUrl();
fileInfo.url = tmp;
```

You can make the property `public` instead:

```
public string url { get; set; }
```

Comment: Crap, how did I miss that! I made sure everything was pub#lic but that! lol, thanks.

Comment: More accessibility notes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763612/default-visibility-for-c-sharp-classes-and-members-fields-methods-etc

Answer (score 0):

You should make `url` property public if you want to access it outside of your class.