# C# private class without nesting in parent class

Tags: c#

Is it possible in C# to define a private class without nesting in a parent class? Below is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do

```
public abstract class ClassA<T> 
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public ClassA(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

private class ClassB : ClassA<int>
{
    public ClassB(int value) 
        : base(value)
    {
    }
}
```

I'd like for `ClassB` to only be accessible by `ClassA`. I'm wondering if what I'm trying to do is possible if the two classes are in the same file. Basically, it would be nice to hide extensions of `ClassA`, but I'd rather not nest too many classes.

Comment: There is something fundamentally wrong here, why would you want a parent class to know anything about its child classes? The point of abstraction is to delegate responsibility for implementation to the child classes so that the parent class does not have to define or know about the implementation. Do you mean you only want child classes to know about parent classes? Marking abstract means nobody can make an instance of ClassA anyway...

Comment: @RonBeyer, it all goes wrong at the point where `abstract` is used instead of `sealed`... ;)

Comment: @RonBeyer I don't really like nesting something as dense as a class -- I can see where it makes sense, though, in this particular instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What would be the purpose of having a private class on its own? you won't be able to reference that class. private classes are only possible inside another classes because the outer class can access it.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm guessing there's no other way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: It conceptually makes no sense that way.

Comment: make `A` internal, and keep `B` and `A` in the same assembly

Comment: Don't need an explicit internal declaration - this is the default behaviour - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763612/default-visibility-for-c-sharp-classes-and-members-fields-methods-etc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521459/what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c - plus it's B that should be internal

Comment: @Orphid, it maybe default, but by specifying it, you are making clear to others that you mean it, rather than just forgot to specify an access modifier. Same applies to `private` within a class.

Comment: @DavidArno that's a matter of taste/ company style. Arguably someone familiar with C# will know the default access modifiers, and to add explicit modifiers can just seem like unnecessary verbiage - i.e. it's context dependent. It's still true to say that you "Don't need an explicit internal declaration". However, your point is taken.

Comment: @Orphid, Sure it's subjective. It's not so much about knowing what the default access modifiers are though; it's all about making your intent clear. It improves maintainability. But it improves it in a subjective way.

Answer (score 1):

The default accesibility of classes is "internal", meaning they can only be accessed (legitimately) from within the declaring assembly. Further restrictions on visibility, as Francisco says, wouldn't make much sense for non-nested types.