# Calling a random function from a .vb file in an .aspx file?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I set up my project as follows:

1. Make empty ASP project
2. Add index.aspx
3. Add url mapping for index to Web.config

Great, it works. Now I want to call a function inside the aspx file, I go ahead and make the function

```
Class Class1
    Public Shared Function SayHi() As String
        Return "Hi"
    End Function
End Class
```

and go on to the aspx file and start writing

```
<% Class1.
```

but intellisense offers no autocomplete, in fact its as if the class doesn't even exist. How can I achieve this simple task?

Comment: where is `Class1`? `Index.aspx.vb` file? if so maybe your `Class1` is really a [`Friend`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76453kax.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) `Index.Class1` class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763612/default-visibility-for-c-sharp-classes-and-members-fields-methods-etc

Comment: You will need `<%= Class1.SayHi %>` (notice the =) to put that value in the page. However, that doesn't fix autocomplete.

Comment: @fra9001 its in Class1.vb file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Class will need to be made **public**:

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Shared Function SayHi() As String
        Return "Hi"
    End Function
End Class
```

And you can use it like this, using the fully qualified name:

```
<div>
    <%= WebApplication1.Class1.SayHi()%>
</div>
```