# Unity C# Attempting to make a lava collider, death script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So far my script is below. I am attempting to create another Collider part to the script, I am attempting to make it so when you collide with Lava, which has a Tag named lava, the player will die. However, I can't get it to call for the die function and I also can't use `OnTriggerEnter(collider,other)` as it gives me an error.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
// Player Movement Start
{

    public float speed;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        rb.AddForce(movement * speed);
    }
            //End of Player Movement Script
    //Pickups Script
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pick Up"))
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
        //End of Pickups Script
    //Health and Death Script
    public float health;                
    public GameObject Ragdoll;             

    public void TakeDamage(float dmg){
        health -= dmg;

        if (health <= 0) {
            Die();
        }
    }
    public void Die() {
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);

    }

 }
//End of Health and Death script
```

Comment: *"as it gives me an error."* Well.. how about sharing that?

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763612/default-visibility-for-c-sharp-classes-and-members-fields-methods-etc),

> The access level for class members and struct members, including
>   nested classes and structs, is private by default.

With this logic, and knowing that `OnTriggerEnter(...)` must be called from outside of your `MonoBehaviour`, you should probably explicitly make it `public`

Also, you say you are trying to run your `Die(...)` method from the `OnTriggerEnter(...)` function, but i dont see that in your code, it should look as follows:

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    switch (other.tag)
    { 
        case "Pick Up": other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            break;
        case "Lava": Die();
            break;
    }
}
```