# How to access to a list of a class globally

Tags: c#, list, class

i've got

```
namespace Example
{
    class TechCollection : List<Tech>
    {
    }
}
```

and then i've got this

```
TechCollection Tee = new TechCollection();
```

in one form but if I insert data I can't access it in other form
Im not sure what's the problem, anyone can help?

Comment: make the class public `public class`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you are on the same assembly you can use `internal`:

```
namespace Example
{
    internal class TechCollection : List<Tech>
    {
    }
}
```

or if you want to access from anywhere use `public`:

```
  namespace Example
    {
        public class TechCollection : List<Tech>
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

By default

```
class TechCollection : List<Tech>
{
}
```

is *internal* and not visible in other assemblies (Has been edited after the comment)

```
internal class TechCollection : List<Tech>
{
}
```

so as mentioned before in comments - use public.

Comment: Nonsense. Default class visibility is internal. You can easily verify it with the help of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt632254.aspx
Default method visibility is private https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Not to be that person, but global anything in C# is a bad design idea. What are you trying to achieve? Do you merely want a List for specific objects that can be reached throughout your application at runtime? If so, maybe think about creating a static singleton class that has a list inside to handle it. Makes it easier to manage in my opinion.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

```
public class Singleton
{
   private static Singleton instance;

   private Singleton() {}

   public IList<object> PseudoGlobalObjects {get;set;}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Singleton();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

Then you can use something like this:

```
 Singleton.Instance.PseudoGlobalObjects.Add(obj);
 Singleton.Instance.PseudoGlobalObjects.Remove(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your class and method public.

> **Classes** and structs that are declared directly within a namespace (in other words, that are not nested within other classes or structs) can be either public or internal. **Internal is the default if no access modifier is specified**.

[Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

[Accessibility Levels (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx)

[Default visibility for C# classes and members (fields, methods, etc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763612/default-visibility-for-c-sharp-classes-and-members-fields-methods-etc)