# Passing List of objects to another form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have Form1 where I want to use the list of objects listaPacienti I created in Form2 but it doesn't work.
Pacient is the class used to generate objects.

Here is Form1's beginning:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        Form2 formPacienti = new Form2();
        List<Pacient> listaPacienti = new List<Pacient>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
```

And here is the beginning of Form2 where I created the list listaPacienti I want to pass to Form1:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {

        List<Pacient>listaPacienti=new List<Pacient>();
        Pacient p1 = new Pacient(0, "Pacient1", 0, 200);
        Pacient p2 = new Pacient(1, "Pacienct2", 0, 100);

        Form1 formMedici = new Form1(listaPacienti);

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listaPacienti.Add(p1);
            listaPacienti.Add(p2);
        }
```

What's wrong because I searched here before and that's how it is recommended to be done and if I wrote something wrong I don't know what it is because in Form2, the parameter "listaPacienti" from the following line

```
Form1 formMedici = new Form1(listaPacienti);
```

shows me this message: "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property "Form2.listaPacienti".

Thank you

Comment: You need to use the correct access modifiders. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3763638/1189566) lists the defaults. None of them are `public`. Additionally, `Form1` does not define a constructor which accepts a `List` as an argument, so even if you had access to `listaPacienti`, that still wouldn't be correct.

Answer (score 4):

There are several things wrong here actually.  The error itself is telling you that you can't *use* a class member when *initializing* a class member.  You're trying to use `listaPacienti` to initialize `formMedici`.  But you *could* initialize it in the constructor.  Something like this:

```
List<Pacient> listaPacienti = new List<Pacient>();
Pacient p1 = new Pacient(0, "Pacient1", 0, 200);
Pacient p2 = new Pacient(1, "Pacienct2", 0, 100);

Form1 formMedici;

public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    listaPacienti.Add(p1);
    listaPacienti.Add(p2);
    formMedici = new Form1(listaPacienti);
}
```

**However**, your `Form1` constructor also needs to *accept* that parameter.  So you either need to modify the existing `Form1` constructor or add a new one:

```
public Form1(List<Pacient> listaPacienti)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // do something with listaPacienti?
}
```

**However**, it's not really clear why you're even doing this.  You create an instance of `Form2` in `Form1`:

```
Form2 formPacienti = new Form2();
```

*Then* you create an instance of `Form1` in `Form2`:

```
Form1 formMedici = new Form1(listaPacienti);
```

This is an infinite recursion waiting to happen.  Do you really want `Form2` to create a *new* instance of `Form1`?  Or do you want to use the *existing* instance of `Form1`?  If the latter, then remove the references to `Form1` entirely from `Form2`.

There are a variety of ways to accomplish the overall goal of what you're trying to do, and which one is ideal depends on more than what's presented here.  But the simplest approach given the information present is probably to just make `listaPacienti` accessible from outside of `Form2`:

```
public List<Pacient> ListaPacienti { get; set; }
Pacient p1 = new Pacient(0, "Pacient1", 0, 200);
Pacient p2 = new Pacient(1, "Pacienct2", 0, 100);

public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ListaPacienti = new List<Pacient>()
    ListaPacienti.Add(p1);
    ListaPacienti.Add(p2);
}
```

Now that `listaPacienti` is a public property, any code which has a reference to an instance of `Form2` can access that property:

```
Form2 formPacienti = new Form2();
// Do other things with formPacienti?
// Either way, here you can access formPacienti.ListaPacienti
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more constructor to form one like this.

```
public Form1(List<Pacient> list)
    {
        this.listaPacienti=list;
        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

After that you can go with this code as you are going.

```
Form1 formMedici = new Form1(listaPacienti);
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the instantiation of `Form1` and `listaPacienti` into the constructor. This existing answer provides a good description of why you are getting this error - [A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439231/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property).

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {

        List<Pacient>listaPacienti;
        Pacient p1 = new Pacient(0, "Pacient1", 0, 200);
        Pacient p2 = new Pacient(1, "Pacienct2", 0, 100);

        Form1 formMedici;

        public Form2()
        {
            listaPacienti=new List<Pacient>();
            formMedici = new Form1(listaPacienti);

            InitializeComponent();
            listaPacienti.Add(p1);
            listaPacienti.Add(p2);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

**Sender Form:**

```
private void btnIniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Main newMain = new Main(this.lsProcesos);
        newMain.ShowDialog();
        this.Show();

    }
```

**Receiver Form:**

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    List<Proceso> lsProcesos;
    public Main(object sender)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lsProcesos = (List<Proceso>)sender;
    }
}
```