# LINQ to XML using Lambda syntax to populate object collection

Tags: lambda, linq-to-xml

I am trying to use LINQ with lambda syntax to load a List of objects from an XML fragment but I am having trouble with the lambda syntax in creating the new object.

Here is the custom class that will hold the data:

```
public class PhysicianInfoModel
{
  string FirstName;
  string LastName;
  string Degree;
}
```

Here is the sample XML I am trying to load the object collection from:

```
<response>
  <control>
    <status>success</status>
    <dtdversion>3.0</dtdversion>
  </control>
  <operation>
    <authentication>
      <status>success</status>
      <userid>jsmith</userid>
    </authentication>
    <result>
      <status>success</status>
      <physicianlist>
        <physician>
          <lastname degree="MD">Smith</lastname>
          <firstname>Paul</firstname>
        </physician>
        <physician>
          <lastname degree="DO">Smith</lastname>
          <firstname>Paul</firstname>
        </physician>
      </physicianlist>
    </result>
  </operation>
</response>
```

I have tried using code such as the following but I know it is not correct as even intellisense in Visual Studio is going all "red squiggly line". In this example `xml` is an `XDocument` object that has loaded the XML listed above.

```
List<PhysicianInfoModel> nodeList = xml.Descendants("physicianlist")
                                .Descendants("physician")
                                .Select(x => new PhysicianInfoModel()
                                {
                                  FirstName = x.?????,
                                  LastName = x.????,
                                  Degree = x.Attribute("degree") // Not working
                                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` in the context of your `Select()` references individual `physician` element so you can't get `degree` attribute directly from `x`. You need to get the child `lastname` element first :

```
List<PhysicianInfoModel> nodeList = 
            xml.Descendants("physicianlist")
               .Descendants("physician")
               .Select(x => new PhysicianInfoModel()
               {
                   FirstName = (string)x.Element("firstname"),
                   LastName = (string)x.Element("lastname"),
                   Degree = (string)x.Element("lastname").Attribute("degree")
               })
               .ToList();
```

Also, all the "red squiggly line" are *probably* because the 3 fields visibility are `private` ([default visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763612/default-visibility-for-c-sharp-classes-and-members-fields-methods-etc)) so it [won't be accessible from outside of the class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) `PhysicianInfoModel`, though I can't be sure if this is the case since you didn't post the actual error message.

Comment: Thanks!. I was missing the `x.Element("lastname")`