# Isn't interface public by default?

Tags: c#, interface, static, access-modifiers

I remember that interface is public by default. Am I wrong? When I tried to implement a "public static" method from an interface. VS told me that the method in the interface is less accessible than the "public static" one. When I added public to the interface it fixed. Isn't interface public by default?

```
interface IDoubleFloatEventInvoker {
 void AddListener(EventName eventName, UnityAction<float, float> unityAction);
}

public static void AddInvoker(EventName eventName, IDoubleFloatEventInvoker invoker)
{
    foreach (UnityAction<float, float> listener in doubleFloatListeners[eventName])
    {
        invoker.AddListener(eventName, listener);
    }
    doubleFloatInvokers[eventName].Add(invoker);
}
```

"VS says IDoubleFloatEventInvoker is less accessible than the AddInvoker function"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default visibility for C# classes and members (fields, methods, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763612/default-visibility-for-c-sharp-classes-and-members-fields-methods-etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interface members are public, but the interface itself will default to `internal` if no accessibility is set, in the same way a class will.

As far as the members being public, that's not exactly 'by default': they are always public, and attempting to set an accessibility on them will result in a compilation error.

Comment: Thank you my man. Is there any way I can set your answer as the selected correct answer?

Comment: I see. The right check. Lol I just did it. Thank you!