# Is a C# field private by default?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Default visibility for C# classes and members (fields, methods, etc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763612/default-visibility-for-c-classes-and-members-fields-methods-etc)

Is a C# field by default private? In general is there a guide (possibly a msdn guide) that specifies these things? When you ommit a modifier, which one is used? Thanks indeed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is private by default. More discussion around it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763612/default-visibility-for-c-classes-and-members-fields-methods-etc) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675575/default-access-modifier-in-c) question.

Answer (score 4):

All type members are private by default.