# Why can't my C++ code see this C# class member?

Tags: c#, c++

I have several custom classes in a C# project that I then reference in a C++ project. The C# code looks something like this

```
namespace AllOptions
{
    public class AllOptions {
        public AlgorithmOptions algOptions{ get; set; }
        public DatabaseOptions dataOptions{ get; set; }
    }

    public class AlgorithmOptions {
        List<Algorithm> algorithms { get; set; }

        public void SetDefaults(){
            this.algorithms.Clear();
        }
    }
    public class Algorithm {
        public bool AllowSalt { get; set; }
    }
    public class DatabaseOptions {
        public List<string> databaseSrouces { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And then from C++ I am trying to access the various parts of the AllOptions but not all of them are coming through.

```
//Is declared at the beginning
public: VerifyOptions::VerifyOptions Options;

//Then later on I try to access the database options and algorithm options
this->Options.databaseOptions->databaseSources = someStringList; //works fine

//This cannot find the algorithm list
this->Options.algorithmOptions->algorithms = someAlgorithmList; //does not work
```

The algorithms says "Class AllOptions::AlgorithmOptions has no member algorithms". Why can't the C++ code see this particular C# member?

*EDIT* My question was tagged as a possible duplicate to this [Default access modifier in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675575/default-access-modifier-in-c-sharp) question. However I believe these to be different questions that happened to result in the same answer. If I am wrong in thinking that please tag it again and I will change it.

Comment: Maybe you have a typo somewhere.  You do have mismatching `databaseSrouces` and `databaseSources` in the C# and C++ code respectively.

Comment: @NathanOliver, That unfortunately is just my poor typing on here, in code all the data types match up

Comment: Can you please use the right tag. You have both `c#` and `c++`.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Is this not an issue containing both?

Comment: Well, they are two different languages, each with their own rules of syntax etc.. It is best that your tag reflect the actual environment that you are developing in.

Comment: Oops - I misread the first sentence - you are using both languages. Me bad!

Comment: @JacobKrall I added an edit explaining why I don't think it is a duplicate, would you disagree with me?

Comment: @WayneO: sure, that's fair.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AlgorithmOptions.algorithms` is a private member. Only the containing class can access its private members. In contrast, `DatabaseOptions.databaseSources` is a public member, and you can access it from anywhere.

Comment: I feel foolish, I had forgotten the standard protection level was private and that is indeed my error. Thank you for the quick reply